# Ubuntu 13.04 sound issue

Tags: 13.04, drivers, sound, hdmi, alsa

I've been messing with various builds from 12.04 (LTS) to 12.10 to 13.04 (and back and forth, doing fresh installs each time from a usb drive, wiping the old partitions off of my disk drive).

I like features of 13.04, but am having major issues not being able to get sound out of my hdmi interface (since I use this PC exclusively as an HTPC).

I tried:

- Going to the [ALSA Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages), download the package: oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms* for my distribution (raring), installed it, and rebooted.
- Going to the [Mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) ubuntu kernels, downloaded version 3.8.8, which is supposed to have a fix for this; downloaded the latest version of the kernels for my architecture (amd64, all), installed it, and rebooted.

Through some of my prior runs, I've done various other things including alsa force-reloads, etc. Nothing seems to get it all working.

Here's as much information as I can think of that I know of that would be relevant. If anyone can provide me with help to this issue, it would be much appreciated.

```
$ uname -s && uname -r && uname -v && uname -p && uname -i && uname -o
Linux
3.8.8-030808-generic
#201304170248 SMP Wed Apr 17 06:49:45 UTC 2013
x86_64
x86_64
GNU/Linux
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD73E1X5 Analog [92HD73E1X5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: 92HD73E1X5 Digital [92HD73E1X5 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770 GHz Edition]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
```

I ran `alsamixer` under `sudo`, and I saw that S/PDIF was [MM] (muted), but I unmuted it. The issue still persists.

Running something like:

`$ speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,1`

For each of the devices from `aplay -l` gives me valid output but no sound for any device. for `0,1`, specifically, I get the following error: `Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy`. The rest don't return an error, but just don't output any sound.

In response to the question about what drivers I am using, I haven't done anything special in regards to drivers, so I am using standard Radeon drivers. Here is the output of `lshw -class sound`:

```
$ sudo lshw -class sound
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f7e60000-f7e63fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:f7f10000-f7f13fff
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the `radeon` or `fglrx` driver?

Comment: @CL. I am using the standard <code>radeon</code> driver. I have updated my question with the output of <code>lshw -class sound</code>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that with the AMD Radeon HD 7700/7800 and the version 3.8.8* kernels, I could follow the following instructions to build proper Debian packages for the fglrx driver (proprietary driver), that will allow me to select "HDMI / DisplayPort" from the Alsa settings in my system tray:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775)

The prior method I used to install the fglrx driver just ran the script in a shell using the gui to run an install that always failed, rather than generating a Debian package that could be used to install the driver through the package manager for my distribution version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [X.org documentation](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/), the driver for your card (HD 7770 = Southern Islands) does not yet support HDMI audio.

Comment: The audio worked before when I was running the quantal distribution packaged in xbmcbuntu which is based off of a standard ubuntu image with preselected packages.